# Which plugin to use for image resizing like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I have following two links

Original image:

http://img.readitlater.com/i/static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/16/realestate/16BOERUMSUB/16BOERUMSUB-master495.jpg

*Resized* image:

[http://img.readitlater.com/i/static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/16/realestate/16BOERUMSUB/16BOERUMSUB-master495/**RS/w280-nc.jpg**](http://img.readitlater.com/i/static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/16/realestate/16BOERUMSUB/16BOERUMSUB-master495/RS/w280-nc.jpg)

I checked with Wappalyzer, but no technology was found.

I want to do something similar like this. Is there is any plugin for that?

**PS:** I know there are lots of plugins available in the market, but I want it similar to this.

Also this is the orginal link of the website:

http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/16/realestate/16BOERUMSUB/16BOERUMSUB-master495.jpg

They added some handler.

Comment: i think that this is enough for you.

[Resize image with jQuery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817871/resize-image-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Both images are different, and saved in different dimensions. I want to say, images are not displayed in HTML page, they are actual image links.

Comment: no, original source is there
http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/16/realestate/16BOERUMSUB/16BOERUMSUB-master495.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This function will resize any images with a specified set of dimensions while preserving the aspect ratio. Be sure to call the function only after every image has been loaded.

```
function resize_images(maxht, maxwt, minht, minwt) {
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  var resize_image = function(img, newht, newwt) {
    img.height = newht;
    img.width  = newwt;
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var img = imgs[i];
    if (img.height > maxht || img.width > maxwt) {
      // Use Ratios to constraint proportions.
      var old_ratio = img.height / img.width;
      var min_ratio = minht / minwt;
      // If it can scale perfectly.
      if (old_ratio === min_ratio) {
        resize_image(img, minht, minwt);
      } 
      else {
        var newdim = [img.height, img.width];
        newdim[0] = minht;  // Sort out the height first
        // ratio = ht / wt => wt = ht / ratio.
        newdim[1] = newdim[0] / old_ratio;
        // Do we still have to sort out the width?
        if (newdim[1] > maxwt) {
          newdim[1] = minwt;
          newdim[0] = newdim[1] * old_ratio;
        }
        resize_image(img, newdim[0], newdim[1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```